# Superfluid across a temperature gradient

Tags: thermodynamics, superfluidity

As I understand it, superfluids cannot sustain temperature gradients; specifically, if a gradient is introduced somewhere on the boundary of the superfluid, a "second sound" thermal wave propagates across through the bulk of the superfluid to bring it to a uniform temperature.

What happens, however, if you force a constant gradient on a superfluid? Say, by immersing a couple of metal contacts in it, one of which is externally heated and the other of which is refrigerated so as to maintain a constant temperature differential between them? Would the superfluid equilibrate to the average temperature of the temperature-forcing contacts?

Comment: Possibly illuminating paper:  http://authors.library.caltech.edu/5540/1/GOOajp03.pdf

Comment: Possibly incredibly technical discussion of superfluid--normal fluid transitions under thermal gradients:  http://arxiv.org/abs/1004.0445